# tf-idf feature weights using sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

this page: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html mentions:

> As tf–idf is a very often used for text features, there is also another class called **TfidfVectorizer** that combines all the option of **CountVectorizer** and **TfidfTransformer** in a single model.

then I followed the code and use fit_transform() on my corpus. How to get the weight of each feature computed by fit_transform()?

I tried:

```
In [39]: vectorizer.idf_
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-5475eefe04c0> in <module>()
----> 1 vectorizer.idf_

AttributeError: 'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute 'idf_'
```

but this attribute is missing.

Thanks

Comment: Judging from the examles in the documentation, I'd say you're supposed to use the return value of `vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)`.

Comment: the return value is a scipy sparse_matrix that store the normalized feature.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Since version 0.15, the tf-idf score of each feature can be retrieved via the attribute `idf_` of the `TfidfVectorizer` object:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ["This is very strange",
          "This is very nice"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
idf = vectorizer.idf_
print dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf))
```

Output:

```
{u'is': 1.0,
 u'nice': 1.4054651081081644,
 u'strange': 1.4054651081081644,
 u'this': 1.0,
 u'very': 1.0}
```

---

As discussed in the comments, prior to version 0.15, a workaround is to access the attribute `idf_` via the supposedly hidden `_tfidf` (an instance of `TfidfTransformer`) of the vectorizer:

```
idf = vectorizer._tfidf.idf_
print dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf))
```

which should give the same output as above.

Comment: This is a bug. Users shouldn't need to access leading `_` members.

Comment: I see. Should ``TfidfVectorizer`` expose a ``idf`` attribute directly? Seems reasonable to have that.

Comment: how to add stopwords in it?

Comment: @YS-L this is just the IDF score, correct, not the full TF-IDF ?

Comment: I have a doubt here regarding calculation since 'nice' or 'strange' have appeared once out of two document shouldn't it's idf equal 1 + log(2)e => 1.69 rather than 1.40 stated above?

Comment: Or if it's base 10 then 1 + log(2)10 gives 1.30 not 1.40

Comment: @InheritedGeek First, you have to multiply the two factors and not sum them. Second, in this case Log(10) Apply. Finally,  the Euclidean (L2) norm is applied when you use TfidVectorizer. For more information read: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction

Answer (score 1):

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449127/sklearn-tfidf-transformer-how-to-get-tf-idf-values-of-given-words-in-documen) on how to get the TF-IDF values of all the documents:

```
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names()
doc = 0
feature_index = X[doc,:].nonzero()[1]
tfidf_scores = zip(feature_index, [X[doc, x] for x in feature_index])
for w, s in [(feature_names[i], s) for (i, s) in tfidf_scores]:
    print w, s

this 0.448320873199
is 0.448320873199
very 0.448320873199
strange 0.630099344518

#and for doc=1
this 0.448320873199
is 0.448320873199
very 0.448320873199
nice 0.630099344518
```

I think the results are normalized by document:

>>>0.448320873199**2+0.448320873199**2+0.448320873199**2+0.630099344518**2
    0.9999999999997548